# Elevated executable can't find OS Tool

Tags: c#, windows, cmd

I'm trying to create a shortcut in my C# WinForm application for users to launch Microsoft's "Digitizer to Monitor Mapping Tool" (MultiDigiMon.exe). However it seems that even if ran as an administrator my applications or cmd processes launched from it can not find the executable in question and I have no idea why.

My Short cut consists of a simple button with the click event hooked to the fallowing function.

```
    private void TouchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
        start.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Windows\\System32";
        start.CreateNoWindow = false;
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        //start.Arguments = "/K \"cd C:\\Windows\\System32 && MultiDigiMon.exe -touch\"";

        Process.Start(start);
    }
```

In my experience on Win10 systems, MultiDigiMon.exe can be always be found in C:\Windows\System32 (assuming the C drive is your root). Additionally the arguments line above was commented out to make the following screen shots as identical as possible.
[image: Command Prompt output comparison]

On the left is the command prompt launched using the above code and on the right is a command prompt launched by typing cmd in to the OS's taskbar and and running the first result as administrator. As you can see both promps are marked as administrator but the left fails to launch MultiDigiMon.exe and won't even list the file exist using the dir command. the right seems to have no issue with either command. (MultiDigiMon.exe dose not seem to do anything at all if multiple touch screen devices are not connected and I do not believe that it give any text output especially if successful).

Finally I have also checked the permission on MultiDigiMon.exe and (with the exception of TrustedInstaller who has full control) everybody has read and execute right. Could someone explain why I can't launch MultiDigimon.exe form the left prompt or directly from my application?

Comment: left picture show `syswow64` folder and right - `system32`. this not related to elevation but to fs redirection for 32 bit apps

Comment: Now I just feel Dumb. That in all likelihood is totally it. thx. Now I just need to figure out how to subvert the redirection in my shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented on by [RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656/rbmm) the issue was that since my application was being compiled to run on any cpu it was treated as a 32 bit application by the file system and redirected all access to the System32 directory to SysWOW64.

To get around this you can substitute "System32" width "Sysnative" as discussed [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cfdf4474-266b-4ef5-8992-7fbdc3147521/accessing-files-from-system32-directory-using-32-bit-application-on-64-bit-machine?forum=netfx64bit). In my case my final code ended up looking like the fallowing.

```
private void TouchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\MultiDigiMon.exe");
    start.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Windows\\System32";
    start.CreateNoWindow = false;
    start.UseShellExecute = false;
    start.Arguments = "-touch";

    Process.Start(start);
}
```

Comment: @RbMm thanks again. If you want to have your answer marked please post one so I can mark it accepted. I'll leave this here in the mean time.